# How do I exclude java files from a jar in maven-jar-plugin?

Tags: maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin

I created a **pom.xml** to compile my project and package it as a jar,
and indeed it comiples and the jar is created - problem is that i got a jar with both classes and java inside, and i only  want the classes inside.

How do I lose the java files? I don’t need them.

this is the **pom.xml** that i created:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>api-interfaces</finalName>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-a-jar</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
              <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
               <exclude>sql/**</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
                 <exclude>*.jar</exclude>
                  <exclude>*.java</exclude>
                   <exclude>default-configs/**</exclude>

          </excludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>
```

[image: this is the jar that i get]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the culprit:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

With this, you explicitly specify that files in `src/main/java`, i.e. the `.java` files, should be included in the jar.

you can either use the standard maven layout and put resources in `src/main/resources`, or explicitly exclude `.java` files using this:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

See [maven resource plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) for more infos, especially the [include/exclude examples](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)

Comment: The solution was indeed to exclude the java: 

 <exclude>**/*.java</exclude> 
and not as i did before: 

 <exclude>*.java</exclude>

Comment: I take it you added this to the `maven-jar-plugin` configuration? Note that by doing so, you only remove the files from the generated jar file. Any other plugin that works with the project's resources will still see them. In most cases, this won't make a difference, but it's something to look out for.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a good reason for binding the `maven-jar-plugin:jar` goal to the `compile` phase explicitly?  The compile phase is intended to [*"compile the source code of the project"*](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), nothing else.

In a `jar` packaging project the `jar:jar` goal is bound to the `package` phase by default which *"take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR."*

The `resources:resouces` goal is bound to the `process-resources` phase which *"copy and process the resources into the destination directory, ready for packaging."*

Binding default goals to non-default phases is more like working against Maven than with it.

By using `src/main/resources` as mentioned by @SillyFreak in his answer you probably don't need this build step definition in your POM at all.